# Add images to Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, directory

Hello I am trying to add images to table.
I made table:

```
    CREATE TABLE program_images
 (
 image_id NUMBER,
 image_filename VARCHAR2(50),
 image BLOB
 );
```

Then made directory where All images are: 
[image]

Finaly made procedure, which insert images to table:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE insert_image_file (p_id NUMBER, p_image_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
   src_file   BFILE;
   dst_file   BLOB;
   lgh_file   BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN

  src_file := BFILENAME ('image_DIR', p_image_name);
   -- insert a NULL record to lock
   INSERT INTO program_images
               (image_id, image_filename, image
               )
        VALUES (p_id, p_image_name, EMPTY_BLOB ()
               )
     RETURNING image
          INTO dst_file;

   -- lock record
   SELECT     image
         INTO dst_file
         FROM program_images
        WHERE image_id = p_id AND image_filename = p_image_name
   FOR UPDATE;

   -- open the file
   DBMS_LOB.fileopen (src_file, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
   -- determine length
   lgh_file := DBMS_LOB.getlength (src_file);
   -- read the file
   DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile (dst_file, src_file, lgh_file);

   -- update the blob field
   UPDATE program_images
      SET image = dst_file
    WHERE image_id = p_id AND image_filename = p_image_name;

   -- close file
   DBMS_LOB.fileclose (src_file);
END insert_image_file;
```

Is that when I call procedure: `EXECUTE insert_image_file(1,'audi_logo.png');` it says me that "non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation" in procedure what is "   DBMS_LOB.fileopen (src_file, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);" this line.
It was first time I use directories, so maybe I forget something to do?

Comment: You really shouldn't be creating objects in the SYS schema. I suggest you can save yourself a lot of trouble if you use a different schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image directory name should be all UPPER_CASE, i.e.

```
src_file := BFILENAME ('IMAGE_DIR', p_image_name);
```

Per the [docs for BFILENAME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions012.htm#SQLRF00610):

```
The directory argument is case sensitive. You must ensure that you specify the
directory object name exactly as it exists in the data dictionary.
```

Comment: In most cases the names of object in the Oracle data dictionary are stored in UPPER CASE. It's possible to specify the names of tables, views, packages, etc, in "lower" or "MiXeD" case (by enclosing the name of the object being created in "Double Quotes") but consensus opinion says that this is "Really Bad Practice". Stick with UPPER CASE for everything. Best of luck.